# Sendmail is not resonding if I give a . or Ctrl D

Tags: linux, sendmail

I configured mail in a linux box but when I give sendmail -v email
it prompts for the subject but when I give . or Ctrl D it doesnt respond . What could be the problem ?

What all service should I check now ?

Comment: It is taking long time , but after that the mail goes.

Comment: It takes approx 2 minutes to get the usual sendmail response , HELO stuff etc. While from other clients which are conigured to the same client sends mails immediately . So clearly the problem is with the machines I am installing .

Answer (score 1):

The canonical "mail is slow" cause is DNS.  I'd strace the `sendmail` process, and see what it hangs on to confirm.

Comment: Yeah DNS is the cause , I resolved it .